# Scrape innertext from html using regex

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I would like to scrape innertext from html block using regex.

Here is the block along with my best parsing effort which is far from perfect: http://www.regexr.com/3andc

What I would like to extract is the string "10 Extremely Popular Youtubers Who Are Now Millionaires"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not use regex to scrape HTML...
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

maybe use HTMLAgilityPack?
https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Edit :

Then try this :
http://regexr.com/3ane7

Comment: Not an option in this case. I am using a proprietary piece of software that will only accept regex input